# UI Design of listboxes in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

in a page 4 menus one by one like the below.

```
APPS
1.sample1
2.sample2

PERSONAL
1.info1
2.info2

Valuble
1.item1
2.item2.

More
1.item1
2.item2
```

like the above APPS,PERSONAL,Valuble,More these are Headings.in that items are binding from Sqlite DB.

intially there are no items .DB is creating .by click on button in that page navigating to another page here i'm binding categories[APPS,PERSONAL---] to combobox and one textbox is there.in that way i'm adding items to mainpage.

functionalty is ok but i taken four listboxes statically placed in that i'm binding the items.but intially no items while db creation.if whenever adding the PERSONAL item first the first listbox was empty and filling the second listbox.if whenever adding MORE items first ,the above listboxes are empty this is bad design i think.

How to design UI for that...

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought this is is an ideal candidate for the LongList selector control of Windows Phone - similar to the contacts page.

Have a look here http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api

I haven't used it myself but would think that you should be able to use it to get the effect you require.